# Why doesn't cheese work on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, webcam, cheese

I recently replaced Windows by Ubuntu on my laptop. Ubuntu however does not recognize my graphics card (ati radeon hd 5470) nor my webcam.
I installed Cheese to solve the problem with the webcam, but when I run Cheese, nothing happens!

I am absolute beginner in Ubuntu so please explain to me in detail what to do.

Comment: It must be a driver issue, because Cheese works just fine on my Lenovo/Ubuntu 12.04. Could you try with 13.10 or 14.04 Beta Live CD?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give some more details. I this a laptop? A desktop? What is your camera model? Please open a terminal, run this command: `lspci | grep -i cam` and add the output to your question. Explain how you run `cheese`, have you tried running it from a terminal? By the way, `cheese` only _uses_ the webcam, it won't magically fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Not every camera works with cheese.  Try another camera package like luvcview, which I found works with at least one camera cheese doesn't.